# Run javascript function but then don't allow it to rerun for x seconds

Tags: javascript

How can I run a javascript function immediately but then not allow the function to run again for x seconds?

The following does add a delay but it then fires the function disableKeyboardDateinputTest  multiples times.

```
function disableKeyboardDateinputTimer() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    disableKeyboardDateinputTest();
  }, 1000);
}

disableKeyboardDateinputTest();
window.addEventListener('resize', disableKeyboardDateinputTimer);
```

Comment: What are you tried?

Comment: what is your code?

Comment: @Evans What you're looking for is generally called *debouncing* a function… (to get you started on the right track)

Comment: I think your problem could be that `resize` is firing multiple times and triggering your handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preventing a function from being called too much is generally known as 'throttling'. The lodash (and underscore) library has a throttle function https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.1#throttle. You could use it like this:

```
function functionToThrottle() {
  //...
  console.log('Called');
}

var x = 10; // seconds

var throttledFunction = _.throttle(functionToThrottle, x * 1000);

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  throttledFunction();
}
```

You need to think about whether you want leading calls (the first call happens immediately) and/or trailing calls (if any calls happen during the throttle period, a single call will happen at the end of the period).

There's a good article on the topic here: https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use Lodash, you could use it's [`throttle`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.0#throttle) helper.

> Creates a throttled function that only invokes func at most once per every wait milliseconds.

Comment: Is it possible to answer this question without simply linking to an external library…?

Comment: Well, of course you could write it on your own. But what's the point?

Comment: Education perhaps…?

Comment: He can educate himself by looking at Lodash's code.

Comment: Is it really necessary to load a library just for this one feature?

Comment: @Evans no - Lodash provides separated modules on NPM (you could probably also extract just one file from the repo itself): https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.throttle